# Stop setInterval after 2 time

Tags: javascript

I have a script

```
<input type="text" value="0" id="count_id">

<input type="button" value="Click Me" id="button_id" onclick="myFunction()">

<script>
function myFunction() {
    
    var data = document.getElementById("count_id").value;
    var  datacount = (parseInt(data) + 1);
    document.getElementById("count_id").value = datacount;  
    document.getElementById("button_id").value = "Clicked";
    
}
setInterval(function(){
document.getElementById("button_id").click();   
}, 3000);
}
</script>
```

by using this they click on button every 3 seconds

I want they click on button only 2 time then stop but they click again again and again

Help me here

Answer (score 0):

You can make a counter and check the condition by the counter value and if the button is clicked 2 times then you can clear the intervak

```html
<input type="text" value="0" id="count_id">

<input type="button" value="Click Me" id="button_id" onclick="myFunction()">

<script>
let count = 0;
function myFunction() {
    
    var data = document.getElementById("count_id").value;
    var  datacount = (parseInt(data) + 1);
    if(count < 2){
        document.getElementById("count_id").value = datacount;  
        document.getElementById("button_id").value = "Clicked";
        count ++;
    }
}

setInterval(function(){
    if(count < 2){
        document.getElementById("button_id").click();   
     }
     else {
       clearInterval()
    }
}, 3000);

</script>
```

Comment: When i apply this on page they stop after 1 time
just 1 click on button then stop

Comment: check this link https://xsportshd.com/bundesliga.html

Comment: Which is the button in xsportshd.com/bundesliga.html ?

Answer (score 0):

You would need a variable to count the number of clicks. Here's an example:

```
// the x variable counts the number of clicks
let x = 0;

function myFunction() {
    var data = document.getElementById("count_id").value;
    var  datacount = (parseInt(data) + 1);
 // only run this code if the button hasn't been clicked more than twice
    if (x < 2) { 
    document.getElementById("count_id").value = datacount;
    document.getElementById("button_id").value = "Clicked";
    }
}
setInterval(function(){
    if (x < 2) {
        document.getElementById("button_id").click();
        x++; // increase x for every click
    }
    else clearInterval(); // clear the loop when x is 2 or more
}, 3000);
}
```